# Kubernetes: How do I delete clusters and contexts from kubectl config?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

`kubectl config view` shows contexts and clusters corresponding to clusters that I have deleted.

How can I remove those entries?

The command

```
kubectl config unset clusters
```

appears to delete all clusters. Is there a way to selectively delete cluster entries? What about contexts?

Answer (score 328, accepted):

`kubectl config unset` takes a dot-delimited path. You can delete cluster/context/user entries by name. E.g.

```
kubectl config unset users.gke_project_zone_name

kubectl config unset contexts.aws_cluster1-kubernetes

kubectl config unset clusters.foobar-baz
```

Side note, if you teardown your cluster using [`cluster/kube-down.sh`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/kube-down.sh) (or [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations#deleting_a_container_cluster) if you use Container Engine), it will delete the associated kubeconfig entries. There is also a planned `kubectl config` [rework](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20605) for a future release to make the commands more intuitive/usable/consistent.

Comment: `kubectl config unset contexts` worked **real nice** thanks!

Comment: I see there is `kubectl config get-contexts` and `kubectl config get-clusters`, but I don't see `kubectl config get-users`, how to list these?

Comment: Another SO user reached out to me via e-mail with the following command for listing users: `kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.users[*].name}'` (their source was [kubectl cheatsheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration))

Answer (score 209):

For clusters and contexts you can also do

```
kubectl config delete-cluster my-cluster

kubectl config delete-context my-cluster-context
```

There's nothing specific for users though, so you still have to do

```
kubectl config unset users.my-cluster-admin
```

Comment: These days there's also `kubectl config delete-user my-user`

Comment: for users you can do `kubectl config unset users`

Answer (score 94):

Run command below to get all contexts you have:

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts

CURRENT   NAME             CLUSTER     AUTHINFO                                NAMESPACE

*         Cluster_Name_1   Cluster_1   clusterUser_resource-group_Cluster_1
```

Delete context:

```
 $ kubectl config delete-context Cluster_Name_1
```

Answer (score 37):

Unrelated to question, but maybe a useful resource.

Have a look at [kubectx + kubens: Power tools for kubectl](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx).

They make it easy to switch contexts and namespace + **have the option to delete**

---

**Change context:**

```
kubectx dev-cluster-01
```

**Change namespace:**

```
kubens dev-ns-01
```

**Delete context:**

```
kubectx -d dev-cluster-01
```

---

> Interested in more power tools and plugins for kubectl? Have a look at **Krew,** [the kubectl plugin manager](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/plugins/). Cannot recommend this enough.

Comment: So if you also want to delete all contexts you might need to deactivate current one with `kubectx -u` and then `kubectx -d current-context-name`

Comment: Yes! I love kubectx. Even if this is a 2 year old post, still need to show the love.