# Kubeconfig is not working when gcloud is reinstalled in /usr/bin/gcloud

Tags: gcloud, kubernetes-helm, kubeconfig

I recently installed by `gcloud` via `apt install gcloud-sdk`. So now `gcloud` is located under `/user/bin/glcoud`. I updated my `~/.kube/config`:

```
xetra11@pop-os:~$ cat ~/.kube/config | grep cmd        
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /user/bin/gcloud
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /user/bin/gcloud
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /user/bin/gcloud
```

But when I run `helm` now it fails to find it:

```
xetra11@pop-os:~$ helm upgrade --install --debug --dry-run ingress-dev -f ingress/values-dev.yaml ingress
Error: Get https://31.2.3.4/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller: error executing access token command "/user/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=fork/exec /user/bin/gcloud: no such file or directory output= stderr=
```

Also `k9s` is not working anymore due the same issue.
Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I cleared the existing kubectl config (via this [How do I delete clusters and contexts from kubectl config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016546/how-do-i-delete-clusters-and-contexts-from-kubectl-config)) and reinit'ed it via `gcloud`. That solved it.

The proper path was `cmd-path: /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud` then. Was not aware this one existed.